# Android App Development - Library android-graphview

Tags: android-studio, android-graphview

I am having a problem with visualization of time series data on graph view library in android studio. When I am trying to plot my graph against very small values(in the intervals of 0.00003) on x-axis, there is no graph. However, when I am try to plot against integer values(in the interval of 1), the graph shown is as expected.

My Working code -

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_time);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int sample_freq = 32768;
    double []  data = intent.getDoubleArrayExtra(DataActivity.EXTRA_TIME_DATA);
    int n = data.length;
    GraphView graph = findViewById(R.id.graph);
    double sample_time = 1/sample_freq;
    DataPoint[] points = new DataPoint[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    {
        points[i] = new DataPoint(i, data[i]);
    }
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(points);
    graph.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
    graph.getViewport().setMinY(-15);
    graph.getViewport().setMaxY(15);
    graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
    graph.getViewport().setMinX(100);
    graph.getViewport().setMaxX(5000);
    graph.getViewport().setScalable(true);
    graph.getViewport().setScalableY(true);
    graph.addSeries(series);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    String message = String.valueOf(n);
    textView.setText(message);
}
```

Code which is not working -

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_time);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int sample_freq = 32768;
    double []  data = intent.getDoubleArrayExtra(DataActivity.EXTRA_TIME_DATA);
    int n = data.length;
    GraphView graph = findViewById(R.id.graph);
    double sample_time = 1/sample_freq;
    DataPoint[] points = new DataPoint[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    {
        points[i] = new DataPoint(i*sample_time, data[i]);
    }
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(points);
    graph.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
    graph.getViewport().setMinY(-15);
    graph.getViewport().setMaxY(15);
    graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
    graph.getViewport().setMinX(0.01);
    graph.getViewport().setMaxX(1);
    graph.getViewport().setScalable(true);
    graph.getViewport().setScalableY(true);
    graph.addSeries(series);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    String message = String.valueOf(n);
    textView.setText(message);
}
```